# AttributeError while scripting Geometry Nodes

Tags: scripting, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to reuse a code provided in an answer here: [Python Geometry Node Trees](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249763/python-geometry-node-trees)

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.curve.primitive_bezier_curve_add()
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='NODES')

curve = bpy.context.active_object
node_group = curve.modifiers[-1].node_group
nodes = node_group.node

group_in = nodes.get('Group Input')
group_out = nodes.get('Group Output')

new_node = nodes.new('GeometryNodeMeshToPoints')

node_group.links.new(group_in.outputs['Geometry'], new_node.inputs['Mesh'])
node_group.links.new(new_node.outputs['Points'], group_out.inputs['Geometry'])
```

but Blender returns something like this (regarding the line with "nodes = node_group.node"):

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Text", line 8, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'node'
```

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: This means the `node_group` variable is `None`. Which in turn means that the curve modifier has no node group set. If you create a raw modifier like this it will not have any nodes assigned to it by default, you need to either set these manually or assign them in the script, like

`curve.modifiers[-1].node_group = bpy.data.node_groups['SomeGroupYouMade']`

Comment: @lukas_t How should I use this script? If I insert it before "nodes = node_group.node", it returns with:

Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Text", line 8, in <module>
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "SomeGroupYouMade" not found'

Comment: @ForceX you're supposed to replace the string SomeGroupYouMade with the name of the group that you created.

Comment: @MartyFouts But is this already in the code provided above or do I have to write something that would create such a group? If so, how do I do it? I'm very sorry, I've started scripting very recently.

Comment: FWIW I modified the answer to add a new node group https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/249779/86891

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 3.1 it is simple.

Change `node` to `nodes` here:

```
nodes = node_group.nodes
```

In 3.2 you shold manually create a node_group according to [this change](https://developer.blender.org/rB08b4b657b64f)

Comment: It still returns with the same AttributeError

Comment: Hm, are you sure? What blender version do you have?

Comment: The version is 3.2.0
This is how it looks: https://i.postimg.cc/QtYyJ58Z/b320.png

Comment: Yep, works fine in 3.1 and has an error in 3.2

Comment: Oh yeah, I switched to 3.1 and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Anyway, I wrote a bug report because this API change hasn't listed. https://developer.blender.org/T99096