# Why does Script not add Input to Active Modifier?

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

Make sure the *Geometry Nodes* editor area is visible then select the default cube and execute the following script to add a *Geometry Nodes* modifier to it with id name **GeometryNodes**

```
import bpy

ctx_override = bpy.context.copy()

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == "NODE_EDITOR":
        ctx_override['area'] = area
        break;

bpy.context.active_object.modifiers.new('GeometryNodes', 'NODES')
```

It creates a new modifier in the modifiers list as shown below. So far all is fine.

[image]

Then execute the following script below to add another *Geometry Nodes* modifier. This script will also set the newly created modifier named **GeometryNodes.001** as the selected or active modifier. But notice that the Input is added to the previously selected modifier. How do I fix that?

```
import bpy

ctx_override = bpy.context.copy()

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == "NODE_EDITOR":
        ctx_override['area'] = area
        break;

bpy.context.active_object.modifiers.new('GeometryNodes.001', 'NODES')
bpy.ops.object.modifier_set_active(modifier='GeometryNodes.001')
bpy.ops.node.tree_socket_add(ctx_override, in_out='IN')
```

[image]

How do I fix that?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/249779/42221) solve your problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Geometry Node Trees](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249763/python-geometry-node-trees)

Comment: I'm sorry but i tried tinkering with the code in that link but i can't figure out how that can specifically fix this problem. could you maybe kindly post a small snippet that does exactly what i asked for? I tried the code but it doesn't create any input socket for the selected/active node.

Comment: or just anything that accomplishes bpy.ops.node.tree_socket_add(ctx_override, in_out='IN') which adds the extra input socket.

Comment: add `node_group.inputs.new("NodeSocketColor", "Color")` after the last statement in the first part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question requires a slight variation on [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249763/python-geometry-node-trees/249779#249779).  After or instead of the statement

```py
nodes = node_group.nodes
```

add

```py
node_group.inputs.new("NodeSocketColor", "Color")
```

so the complete code becomes, in your example,

```py
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='NODES')  

curve = bpy.context.active_object

def new_GeometryNodes_group():
    ''' Create a new empty node group that can be used
        in a GeometryNodes modifier.
    '''
    node_group = bpy.data.node_groups.new('GeometryNodes', 'GeometryNodeTree')
    inNode = node_group.nodes.new('NodeGroupInput')
    inNode.outputs.new('NodeSocketGeometry', 'Geometry')
    outNode = node_group.nodes.new('NodeGroupOutput')
    outNode.inputs.new('NodeSocketGeometry', 'Geometry')
    node_group.links.new(inNode.outputs['Geometry'], outNode.inputs['Geometry'])
    inNode.location = Vector((-1.5*inNode.width, 0))
    outNode.location = Vector((1.5*outNode.width, 0))
    return node_group

# In 3.2 Adding the modifier no longer automatically creates a node group.
# This test could be done with versioning, but this approach is more general
# in case a later version of Blender goes back to including a node group.
if curve.modifiers[-1].node_group:
    node_group = curve.modifiers[-1].node_group    
else:
    node_group = new_GeometryNodes_group()
    curve.modifiers[-1].node_group = node_group

nodes = node_group.nodes
node_group.inputs.new("NodeSocketColor", "Color")
```

By the way, the use of the *context override dictionary* is deprecated in 3.2 and scheduled to be removed from 3.1  If you want to override context in 3.2 and later you should use [`temp_override`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Context.html#bpy.types.Context.temp_override) instead

Comment: thank u very much for your help very much appreciated sorry i ran out of votes, il give a vote up tomorrow.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie you're very welcome.  No problem on the vote; just glad I could help.

Answer (score -2):

You have context override from previous step, when new modifier hadn't been created yet.

But I suggest not using ops in the scripts. It is very annoying to set up a context override without information about what has to be overridden. I see that you have some non-ops functions, so maybe replace every one?

3.1:

```
import bpy

gnmod =  bpy.context.active_object.modifiers.new('GeometryNodes.001', 'NODES')
ins = gnmod.node_group.inputs
ins.new("NodeSocketColor", "Color")
```

Is that simple without using ops. But in the case if you want to run this in 3.2:

3.2/3.1:

```
import bpy

gnmod =  bpy.context.active_object.modifiers.new('GeometryNodes.001', 'NODES')
# 3.2 check
if gnmod.node_group is None:
    ng = bpy.data.node_groups.new("Vox", "GeometryNodeTree")
    input = ng.nodes.new("NodeGroupInput")
    output = ng.nodes.new("NodeGroupOutput")
    input.location = (-1000,0)
    output.location = (1000,0) 
    ng.inputs.new("NodeSocketGeometry", "Geometry")
    ng.outputs.new("NodeSocketGeometry", "Geometry")
    ng.links.new(input.outputs[0], output.inputs[0])
    gnmod.node_group = ng
ins = gnmod.node_group.inputs
ins.new("NodeSocketColor", "Color")
```

Comment: i already tried rearranging it, same result. please test it first. and can you please post the working code as answer.

Comment: Foremost - that version do you use? It looks like 3.1, because in 3.2 you have to make node tree also.

Comment: oh yeah i remember in 3.2 they have this temp context thing. im on 3.1

Comment: No, In 3.2 you have to set up node group also

Comment: yeah anyway im on 3.1. can u help me solve this?

Comment: I've updated the answer

Comment: Your 3.2/3.1 code doesn't work in 3.2.  The node group you create doesn't have any nodes.  In particular, it's missing a Group Output node.

Comment: Yep! It's because node group also created without nodes, you have to add them manualy.

Comment: Yes, like [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/249779/42221)

Comment: @MartyFouts  I've updated the answer