# Create a new asset library and get it in a variable

Tags: python, asset-browser

How can I create a new asset library, like what `bpy.ops.preferences.asset_library_add()` does, but also get the new library stored in a variable?

The operator just returns `{'FINISHED'}`. Normally there's a separate function like `D.materials.new()` which returns the created datablock, but I can't find any similar `.new()` function for asset libraries which are stored as part of the preferences in `C.preferences.filepaths.asset_libraries`.

Feasibly I could store a list of asset libraries, create a new one, and then examine the libraries to see which is not present in the old list, but this seems like a silly workaround.

Edit: I guess it's maybe intentional that this can't be done easily, as you also have to handle saving the user's preferences.

Comment: OPS are designed to be used in the interface, not in the Python. I would suggest watching my minused answer here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/267405/why-does-script-not-add-input-to-active-modifier/267406#267406 why it is better not to use OPS.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I'm asking :)

Comment: Bpy.ops **are** meant to be used in Python: there are some parts of the API, like some baking, that can only be accessed through  bpy.ops. If they weren’t, then there would be no Python interface to them. At this time the asset library interface is in flux and a lot has simply not been implemented yet.

Comment: Yeah at first glance I'm inclined to believe that your "workaround" is the solution. At least for now, looking through the docs, it seems like they're working on [adding](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Context.html?highlight=assethandle#bpy.types.Context.asset_file_handle) to the API for asset libraries

Comment: follow up on `bpy.ops`:  The Blender Python fine manual [Gotchas](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_gotcha.html#using-operators) section says "Blender’s operators are tools for users to access, that can be accessed with Python too which is very useful." `bpy.ops` should be avoided in the case where 1) performance is critical and 2) there exists a low level alternative.  If either of these is not true, than by all means use `bpy.ops` but be aware of gotchas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Asset libraries are a [property collection](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.bpy_prop_collection.html) and so there is no low level add method.  However, `bpy.ops.preferences.asset_library_add()` follows the common practice of adding the new library to the end of the asset library list, so you don't have to compare two versions of the list and can use this idiom:

```py
bpy.ops.preferences.asset_library_add()
new_library = bpy.context.preferences.filepaths.asset_libraries[-1]
```

to retrieve a reference to the just added library.  This, of course, only works up until the next time you perform an operation that modifies the library list.

Comment: Note the things you can do with this construct is get or set `new_library.name` and `new_library.path` according to the docs https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UserAssetLibrary.html